# Удалить все заданные слова из массива данных

Tags: php, фильтры

Есть одномерный массив `$arr`, каждый элемент которого содержит текст. Этот текст может включать, а может не включать имена (`Маша, Саша, Дима, Катя, Василиса Иннокентьевна, Клавдий Цезаревич, Иван Дурак` и т.д. и т.п - список большой).

Подскажите, как можно средствами *PHP* отфильтровать эти самые имена?
Список имен сохранен в отдельном файле `filtr.txt`

**Требуется удалить не элементы массива, содержащие имена, а только сами имена из текста элемента.**

Можно ли это сделать без использования регулярных выражений?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$arr = [
  "Иван купил, а Иван продал",
  "Лариса пришла",
  "Кот увидел",
  "Сотрудник Дима ушёл"
];
$names = [
  "Иван",
  "Лариса",
  "Дима"
];

foreach($arr as $key => $text) {
  $text = str_replace($names, "", $text);

  $arr[$key] = $text;
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) " купил, а  продал"
  [1]=>
  string(25) "лариса пришла"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "Кот увидел"
  [3]=>
  string(28) "Сотрудник  ушёл"
}
```

Спасибо за [подсказку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981038/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/981046?noredirect=1#comment1650375_981046) @u_mulder.

Comment: Если вы не знали - то первым аргументом в `str_replace` можно передавать массив, так что внутренний цикл не требуется.

Comment: @u_mulder в `str_replace` все аргументы могут быть массивами _(не только первый)_

Answer (score 5):

вариант без цикла:

```
$arr   = array(
  "Иван купил, а Иван продал",
  "лариса пришла",
  "Кот увидел",
  "Сотрудник Дима ушёл",
);
$names = array(
  "Иван"   => "",
  "лариса" => "Ольга",
  "Дима"   => "",
);


$arr = explode(chr(1), strtr(implode(chr(1), $arr), $names));


var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Улучшенный вариант предыдущего ответа выглядит так:

```
<?php
$arr = [
  "Иван купил, а Иван продал",
  "лариса пришла",
  "Кот увидел",
  "Сотрудник Дима ушёл"
];
$names = [
  "Иван",
  "Лариса",
  "Дима"
];

foreach($arr as &$text) {
    $text = str_replace($names, '', $text);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Ещё один вариант, только вместо перебора `forech`, используется `array_map`:

```
function rmName($name)
{
    $names = [
        "Иван",
        "Лариса",
        "Дима"
    ];
    return str_replace($names, "", $name);
}
$arr = [
    "Иван купил, а Иван продал",
    "Лариса пришла",
    "Кот увидел",
    "Сотрудник Дима ушёл"
];
$result = array_map("rmName", $arr);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного добавлю про array_map и array_walk

```
<?php

$arr = [
  "Иван купил, а Иван продал",
  "Лариса пришла",
  "Кот увидел",
  "Сотрудник Дима ушёл"
];
$names_raw = file_get_contnent('filtr.txt');
$names = explode(PHP_EOL, $names_raw);

// Если нужен другой массив
$arr2 = array_map(function($value) use ($names) {return str_replace($names, '', $value);}, $arr);
// Если нужно поменять текущий
array_walk($arr, function(& $item, $key, $names) {$item = str_replace($names, '', $item);}, $names);
```

Наверное стоит пояснить вкратце:

[array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) применяет callback функцию ко всем элементам массива и отдаёт новый массив

[array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php) применяет callback функцию к каждому элементу массива, и сообщает удалось ему это сделать или нет, в качестве третьего аргумента можно передать 3 параметр для callback функции

Update: Имена из файла